# Alternativa a Mailto para adjuntar archivos y estilizar correo

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una pagina web donde en una parte debe crearse un mail, en el cuál se deberán adjuntar un archivo pdf y debo estilizar el cuerpo. 
Agregué unas etiquetas html en el cuerpo del mensaje para así estilizarlo y use el atributo "attached" para agregar el archivo. En opera funciono todo a la perfección, pero cuando uso otro navegador no lo interpreta y no acepta el archivo. He investigado mucho y no se puede hacer lo que quiero con mailto, o al menos no en otros navegadores que no sean opera.

Me gustaría saber si conocen alguna alternativa de mailto que me permita hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: No es posible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment